# RemoteServiceException with no extra info

Tags: android, exception, remoteview, android-remoteview

After updating a version of our app we started receiving the following crash reports on the Google Play Console:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1867)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6753)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:482)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

More info:

- The crash ONLY occurs on API versions 27 (Android 8.1) and 28.
- The crash occurs on multiple devices (primarily OnePlus6)
- The crash is NOT reported via fabric's Crashlytics
- The latest app updated changed `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` to 28

Any idea on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: This issue disappeared by itself after updating the app dependencies

Comment: What did you exactly update? I'm having the issue after updating targetSdkVersion to 28.